# Use of mediator design pattern with mailing list implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, email, mediator

I have implemented the following scenario for the Mediator pattern sample:

`MailingListMediator`: Manages the subscription and send the mail back and forth.

- `JavaMailingList`
- `SQLMailingList`

(Colleagues)`MailUsers`: They can login, subscribe to the mailing list, send mails to mailing list.

- `GmailUsers`
- `YahooUsers`

My implementation looks like this:

**`MailingListMediator`**

```
public abstract class MailingListMediator {

    protected List<MailUser> mailingList;

    public MailingListMediator() {
        this.mailingList = new ArrayList<MailUser>();
    }

    public void sendMail(String message){
        for(MailUser mUser:mailingList){
            System.out.println("Mail message: '"+message+"' sent to "+ mUser.getMailId());
        }
    }
    public abstract String subscribe(MailUser mailUser);
}
```

**`MailUser`**

```
public abstract class MailUser {
    public abstract void login(String mailID);
    public abstract void sendMailToMailingList(MailingListMediator mailingList, String message);
    public abstract String getMailId();
}
```

**`GmailUser`**

```
public class GmailUser extends MailUser {
    String mailID;

    @Override
    public void login(String mailID) {
        this.mailID = mailID;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMailToMailingList(MailingListMediator mailingList, String message)     {
        mailingList.sendMail(message);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMailId() {
        if(mailID != null){
            return mailID;
        }else{
            return "Login First";
        }    
    }
}
```

**`YahooUser`**

```
public class YahooUser extends MailUser {
    String mailID;

    @Override
    public void login(String mailID) {
        this.mailID = mailID;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMailToMailingList(MailingListMediator mailingList, String message) {
        mailingList.sendMail(message);    
    }

    @Override
    public String getMailId() {
        if(mailID != null){
            return mailID;
        }else{
            return "Login First";
        }
    }
}
```

**`JavaMailingList`**

```
public class JavaMailingList extends MailingListMediator {
    private final String mailingListId = "java";

    @Override
    public String subscribe(MailUser mailUser) {    
        mailingList.add(mailUser);
        return mailingListId;
    }
}
```

**`SQLMailingList`**

```
public class SQLMailingList extends MailingListMediator {
    private final String mailingListId = "sql";

    @Override
    public String subscribe(MailUser mailUser) {    
        mailingList.add(mailUser);
        return mailingListId;
    }
}
```

**`ForumUsers`**

```
public class ForumUsers{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MailingListMediator javaMailingList = new JavaMailingList();
        //User 1
        MailUser gmail = new GmailUser();
        gmail.login("iamgmail@gmail.com");
        javaMailingList.subscribe(gmail); // He subscribes

        //User 2
        MailUser yahoo = new YahooUser();
        yahoo.login("iamyahoo@yahoo.com");
        javaMailingList.subscribe(yahoo); // He subscribes

        //gmail user sends a question to the Java Mailing List
        gmail.sendMailToMailingList(javaMailingList, "How to excel in Java??!!");
    }
}
```

Does this implementation adhere to the Mediator Design? What improvements can be made?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the Mediator pattern, but I think your code is not complex enough to make good use of the pattern. Take your `JavaMailingList` and `SQLMailingList`, what is the difference between those classes ? The value of `mailingListId`. The implementation of `subscribe` is exactly the same, you add the same variable to the class. If your `MailingListMediator` would look like :

```
public class MailingListMediator {
    private final String mailingListId;
    protected List<MailUser> mailingList;

    public MailingListMediator(String mailingListId) {
        this.mailingList = new ArrayList<MailUser>();
        this.mailingListId = mailingListId;
    }

    public void sendMail(String message){
        for(MailUser mUser:mailingList){
            System.out.println("Mail message: '"+message+"' sent to "+ mUser.getMailId());
        }
    }
    public String subscribe(MailUser mailUser) {
        mailingList.add(mailUser);
        return mailingListId;
    }
}
```

There is suddenly no need for  `JavaMailingList` and `SQLMailingList`.

The same principle apply to `YahooUser` and `GmailUser`. Those classes are almost a copy-paste of each other. Same implementation for all the methods and adding the same variable to the class. Why is `mailID` an attribute in the children classes but not in `MailUser`? I could repeat the same process that I used for `MailingListMediator` and I could remove `YahooUser` and `GmailUser`.

My conclusion is your code looks like trying to be complicated when in fact it is not. You want to try the Mediator pattern ? Well wait when you will need it, do not force your code into a pattern. Pattern will be useful when you need it, otherwise it will only make your code less readable and harder to maintain.

Since you wanted to implement the Mediator pattern, I will expand more on that part. You do have a mediator pattern implemented. Your "colleagues" do interact between each other through the mediator that is the `MailingList`. There isn't a `MailUser` that interact directly with each other, that is the main point of the mediator pattern. Do know that your example is a little weak. I would suggest you, if you really want to test the mediator pattern, try a to code a chat application. This could be a good exercise since you will have a lot of users that will need to communicate, but you don't want the class to be tightly coupled.

Comment: Thanks for that. I get what you are telling. But all I wanted to do is not a real implementation of a Mailing List, but to simulate a scenario to understand how the Mediator Pattern works.

Comment: @Sowmiya From what I'm reading of the mediator pattern it looks like a good implementation of the pattern.

Comment: @Sowmiya this could be a good link to read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373598/when-would-you-use-the-mediator-design-pattern

Answer (score 2):

`login` is a setter method and should be named `setLogin`, or even better, only used in the constructor to make subclasses of `MailUser` immutable

Comment: Since,its not a real implementation, but just a simulation of Mediator pattern, I have done it with assumption like login logic will differ for different type of mail users.

Comment: This you should have a `MailUser(address)` constructor and a `login()` instead.

Comment: Understood.I have done those design changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you just have several classes that implement the same `MailUser`  interface. That's just inheritance.

I'm not familiar with mediator pattern, but I see it like a hub. From Wikipedia:

> The essence of the Mediator Pattern is to "Define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact".

Here, the different MailUsers don't interact with each other.

Comment: Mailusers do interact with each other, through the MailingList. (MailUser can send mails to MailingList, which encloses other(subscribed) MailUsers).

Comment: That would be a mediator pattern if the YahooMailUser and GmailMailUser had different interfaces. But here, you simply have a MailingList that contains MailUsers of different implementations. See also [Head first on design patterns](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/patterns/0596007124/adot-leftover-patterns/mediator_in_actionhellip_html)

Comment: I get it. But as I see in [this link's chatroom example](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html), the Colleague's can be of same type also, is what I understand. Correct me if I am wrong.